# Connection failed to MySQL after upgrade AWS RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have upgrade instance class of mysql rds on aws from tiny to small. After it complete upgrading I cannot connect to that database from my local machine.

I'm very new to aws rds please help.

(I use dbeaver and mysqlworkbench to test connection on my macbook)

I also try create new one with the same security group without encryption the new database connection works fine!

Comment: are you getting any error? share the error message.

Comment: you will have to use SSL cert if your db is encrypted

Comment: @AmitVerma error: connection timed out. communications link failure.

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag I tried restore my db backup to new one with encryption. It's works.